# Jittery volume slider while adjusting volume

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I have a slider to adjust volume that is extremely jittery while sliding. I've discovered if you click on the slider and drag your cursor above or below the area, the slider moves extremely smooth but the instant that you put your cursor over the slider icon to move it, it gets jittery. Any thoughts? I'm using Howler.js!

**Here's my site so far where you can test:** https://www.unearthapp.io/Album/91

**Note**, you need to click play on the song (by hovering over the track) before the volume slider becomes adjustable. Volume slider is in bottom right corner.

Relevant code:

```
barEmpty.addEventListener('click', function(event)
{
    var per = event.offsetX / 100;
    player.volume(per);
});
sliderBtn.addEventListener('mousedown', function()
{
    window.sliderDown = true;
});
sliderBtn.addEventListener('touchstart', function()
{
    window.sliderDown = true;
});
volume.addEventListener('mouseup', function()
{
    window.sliderDown = false;
});
volume.addEventListener('touchend', function()
{
    window.sliderDown = false;
});
var move = function(event)
{
    if(window.sliderDown)
    {
        var x = event.offsetX || event.touches[0].clientX;
        var startX = 100 * 0.015;
        var layerX = x - startX;
        var per = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, layerX / 100));
        player.volume(per);
    }
};
volume.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
volume.addEventListener('touchmove', move);
```

Comment: Use `inspect` and see there you are getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'volume' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.move (player.js:398)` Solve that first

Comment: @Durga that's because you need to click play on the song before the song is loaded (which has the volume attribute), will be fixing that shortly, but that isn't the issue as to why it jitters

Comment: If you are using jQuery , you can go for [ui slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: @Durga I've built my application around Howler.js audio player. Which has this built in slider, I've adjusted it a bit for my situation, but obviously what I changed makes the slider freak out, just dont know what